# python requests memory leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks, python-requests, python-3.4

I have the problem of memory leaks. By experiments, I came to realize that it is the code I have gradually eating up all available memory:

```
def my_func(url):
    with requests.Session() as r:
        r.get(url)
ThreadPool(128).map(my_func, open('urls.txt'))
```

Ubuntu Linux, Python 3.4, all up-do-date. Any ideas?

Comment: On a side note, passing urls with newlines won't work too well.

Comment: this is a pseudocode, am using url.strip()

Comment: The performance characteristics of a thread pool are perfectly fine for I/O operations. Also, the method in the top answer you linked uses a thread pool executor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the real problem.

I think you can use 'With Context' to avoid memory leak

```
import requests
import json
from contextlib import closing

url = 'https://cn.bing.com/'
with closing(requests.get(url)) as resp:
    print(resp._content)
```

Or you should add the headers to close the connection with server, can keep less connections with one server, if your connection error is on server side:

```
headers = {'Connection': 'close'}
```